vscode setting location for workspace disabled extensions
Where does vscode store the fact that an extension has been disabled for a workspace?
I see that workspace extension recommendations are stored in ./vscode/extensions.json
but I can't find where the setting is stored for disabling extensions in a workspace.
Also asked here, but no answer.

VSC has an sqlite3 database for each workspace, most likely it stores the info there, use an sqlite3 db viewer to see the content, and it might have a global db with info on extensions disabled in case you create a new workspace

Thanks for the hint @rioV8, it is indeed in an sqlite db file.
This doc also helped https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customization/userandworkspace/#user-and-workspace-settings
Mine was located in C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\877f68601cef052464e7a575b58802f4\state.vscdb
Within that file the table is 'ItemTable'
And the key is 'extensionsIdentifiers/disabled'
